# Raphael JS - Liimiting text legnth

Tags: javascript, svg

This is my code:

```
var textObj = r.text(x, y, text);
    textObj.attr({ "fill": TextAttr.color, cursor: Shape.cursor, "font-size": TextAttr.font_size, "width": 0 });
```

And this is the outcome.

[image: bubbles]

How can I limit the text legnth.

I see that the text is defined as svg text.

So i am looking for something like 'word-break: break-all;' for svg text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis`, even from your css, cause svg tags are regular html tags. You can provide additional params into attr object, or write it directly in your css:

```
white-space: nowrap; 
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

It's not widely support in modern browsers, though.